# Can protobuf field name start with a number?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have a table that I wish to encode into a protobuf format.

| MyTable columns | Types |
| --- | --- |
| 24hr_support | varhcar |
| active | boolean |
| subscription_type | varchar |

Is it allowed to define the message type like below, with the name of the first field `24hr_support` starting with a number?

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

message MyTable {
  string 24hr_support = 1;
  bool active = 2;
  string subscription_type = 3;
}
```

I can't find any reference to this in the [language Guide](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#simple:%7E:text=Guide%20(proto%203)-,Language%20Guide%20(proto%203),-This%20topic%20covers).

Answer (score 0):

The [Language Specification](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/proto3-spec/) describes [identifiers](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/proto3-spec/#identifiers) and `fieldName` as:

```
letter { letter | decimalDigit | "_" }
```

So, field names may not start with numbers (`decimalDigit`'s) but may include numbers after an initial `letter`.

You can readily verify this by using `protoc` to compile your proto file:

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD} \
--python_out=${PWD} \
--pyi_out=${PWD} \
${PWD}/foo.proto
```

```
foo.proto:4:12: Need space between number and identifier.
foo.proto:4:10: Expected field name.
```